# Extract a number from String in SQL

Tags: sql, string

I have the following string:

"FLEETWOOD DESIGNS   535353110XXXXX"    (The X's are actually numbers I just wanted to hide them here)

Does anyone know how can I search through Strings in SQL and extract numbers that are greater then lets say 10 characters long?

Comment: What Database Engine are you using?

Comment: so the numbers might not be in the same positions every time right?

Comment: The numbers can be anywhere and the string will be much bigger. I am using SQLSERVER 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention the DB engine, so we don't know what features are available...

If regexpressions are available then pattern like `\d{10,}` would match numbers with 10 or more digit.

In mySQL [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) can only return true or false (0 or 1) so you'd have to use some ugly hack like

```
SELECT
  LEAST(
     INSTR(field,'0'),
     INSTR(field,'1'),
     INSTR(field,'2'),
     INSTR(field,'3'),
     INSTR(field,'4'),
     INSTR(field,'5'),
     INSTR(field,'6'),
     INSTR(field,'7'),
     INSTR(field,'8'),
     INSTR(field,'9')
  ) AS startPos,
  REVERSE(field) AS backward,
  LEAST(
     INSTR(backward,'0'),
     INSTR(backward,'1'),
     INSTR(backward,'2'),
     INSTR(backward,'3'),
     INSTR(backward,'4'),
     INSTR(backward,'5'),
     INSTR(backward,'6'),
     INSTR(backward,'7'),
     INSTR(backward,'8'),
     INSTR(backward,'9')
  ) AS endPos,
  SUBSTRING(field, startPos, endPos - startPos + 1)
FROM tab
WHERE(field REGEXP '[0-9]{10,}')
```

but this isn't perfect - it would extract false substring for string like "ABC 9 A 1234567891", not to mention that it is probably so slooooow that it is faster to go througt data by hand.

Answer (score 1):

This a quite old post but might help anyone else. I was searching for an user defined function in `SQL Server` to extract only the numbers of a given string, and, surprisingly I could not find exactly what I was looking for.

Let me put here the code of a function to "Extract a number from string in SQL" (valid for `SQL Server`). This is taken from the fantastic blog of [Pinal Dave](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/11/sql-server-udf-user-defined-function-to-extract-only-numbers-from-string/), I've modified it just to return `NULL` is a `NULL` value is passed to the function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ExtractInteger](@String VARCHAR(2000))
    RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Count INT
    DECLARE @IntNumbers VARCHAR(1000)
    SET @Count = 0
    SET @IntNumbers = ''

    IF @String IS NULL
        RETURN NULL;

    WHILE @Count <= LEN(@String)
    BEGIN
        IF SUBSTRING(@String,@Count,1) >= '0' AND SUBSTRING(@String,@Count,1) <= '9'
        BEGIN
            SET @IntNumbers = @IntNumbers + SUBSTRING(@String,@Count,1)
        END
        SET @Count = @Count + 1
    END

    RETURN @IntNumbers
END
```

**Tests**

```
select '"' + dbo.ExtractInteger('1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h9i') + '"'
GO
select '"' + dbo.ExtractInteger('abcdefghi') + '"'
GO
select '"' + dbo.ExtractInteger(NULL) + '"'
GO
select '"' + dbo.ExtractInteger('') + '"'
GO
```

**Results**

```
"123456789"
""
NULL
""
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SUBSTRING('FLEETWOOD DESIGNS 535353110XXXXX', 18, 32)
```

You could also use `LEN()` to get the length of the string itself. If you know the serial number length, you can just subtract that from the end index to get your start index of the substring.

Comment: good idea, however the number could be located anywhere in the string

Answer (score 0):

It could be done like this

```
Declare @X     varchar(100)
Select     @X=    'Here is where15234Numbers'
--
Select     @X=    SubString(@X,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@X),Len(@X))
Select     @X=    SubString(@X,0,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',@X))
--// show result 
Select     @X
```